# Create Sqlite database in Codename One using NetBeans

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to connect database and wanna create database table in Codename One. can someone guide me.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Database javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html) and the [SQL section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql).

Also check out this [SQL Explorer demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sql-explorer-global-toolbar-location-docs.html).